# How to install MCrypt PHP Extension on CentOS 7.0 x64

Tags: php, laravel-4, mcrypt, centos7

I am using laravel framework. laravel project running requirement is MCrypt. i m trying to install but i m facing error

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-09-18 13:25:27 ERROR 404: Not Found.

yum install php-mcrypt

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- base: centos.someimage.com
- extras: mirrors.mit.edu
- updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu

No package php-mcrypt available.

Error: Nothing to do

Comment: How are you trying to install it?  From where?  Are you just doing `yum install php-mcrypt`?  Have you updated your repositories first (`yum update`)?  (I think those `yum` commands are correct.  I haven't used CentOS in a while)

Comment: yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.someimage.com
 * extras: mirrors.mit.edu
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
No package php-mcrypt available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 5):

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm

yum install php-mcrypt*
```

Comment: what does the * do in yum install php-mcrypt*?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install EPEL repository.

http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/

Then try to install mcrypt extension

Open terminal as root (su)

> wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm
>
> rpm -ivh epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm
>
> yum update
>
> yum install php-mcrypt*

Comment: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.someimage.com
 * extras: mirrors.mit.edu
 * updates: mirror.lug.udel.edu
No Match for argument: install
No package install available.
No Match for argument: php-mcrypt*
No package php-mcrypt* available.
No packages marked for update

Comment: Did you enable EPEL repository by: # wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm ?

Comment: # wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm

Comment: error: open of epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm failed: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-1.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install epel-release-7-1.noarch.rpm

yum install php-mcrypt*

restart Apache

sudo service httpd restart
```